# Why `the sql may be wrong` error appeared when adding `order by` to query statement in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What may cause `the sql may be wrong` error when adding `order by` to the Apache IoTDB query? My query statement is

```
select CY1, CY3 
from root.*.line_id.17.machine.id.1715 
where timestamp<1660268809952 order by timestamp limit 1
```

How should I correct my statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `order by time desc` instead of `order by timestamp`. You can also directly use `order by time` grammar in Apache IoTDB for other time-related scenarios.